# "Could not find the correct Provider" error when dealing with separate file from main.dart

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I am trying to make an separate file for a simple list of notes.

I have the following code in lib/pages/list_entries.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class NotesState extends ChangeNotifier {
  var arrNotes = [];
}

class ListEntriesPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ListEntriesPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<ListEntriesPage> createState() => _ListEntriesState();
}

class _ListEntriesState extends State<ListEntriesPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var noteState = context.watch<NotesState>();

    if (noteState.arrNotes.isEmpty) {
      return Center(
        child: Text('No note yet.'),
      );
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

> Error: Could not find the correct Provider<NotesState> above this ListEntriesPage Widget

I'm confused, because isn't exactly where my class NotesState is declared, immediately above the ListEntriesPage class?

I've tried to look up other questions but the code samples are far too complex, I'm obviously missing the basics here.

Note that the ListEntriesPage() is called from the class _MyHomePageState in main.dart.
I mention that because I had a very similar code in main.dart, which was working, and I tried to move it to a separate file and adapt the code and I can't get it to work. So I'm thinking it has to do with the scope of something...

Answer (score 0):

This might not be a perfect explanation, but hopefully it help beginners.
By "above this ListEntriesPage Widget", they meant the parent scope, not a few lines before.

Also, the missing provider in question is not the class NotesState, but a call to the ChangeNotifierProvider function.

So, in my case, I needed to go in the main.dart file, and change:

```
void main() {

  //Some truncated code

  runApp(const MyApp());

}
```

to:

```
void main() {

  // Some truncated code

  runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => NotesState(),
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
  );

}
```

Now the app know to use the NotesState class.

This documentation/tutorial helped me greatly:
https://docs.flutter.dev/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple